# Can i implement google authenticator (2-steps authentification) on Google Home?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, google-authenticator

All is in the title,

I would like to know if it's possible to implement google authenticator in a google home app ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would be possible. Google Authenticator is based on TOTP (Time-based One-time Password Algorithm), now standard RFC 6238.

There's also more info on the [google-authenticator Github wiki](https://github.com/google/google-authenticator/wiki).

Overall, to do this you'd need to create an implementation of the right protocols and you could generate codes. However, the issues you would encounter would be account linking (as the initial setup codes are long and unpronounceable) and possibly security concerns with people being able to ask for a security code + it just blurting it out for all to hear.

[TOTP on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm)

Comment: Thanks, so, it's bit complicated actually....

For you, which method is the most securised for operations in Google home ?

I tried to use to vocal recognition ( with the id of my voice) but its look not working really good ( my friend pass through easily.... almost same voice apaprently)

thanks for your advice